# Linux execute file using PHP (XAMPP)

Tags: php, linux, xampp

This is way harder than it looks like, I think I am encountering some kind of permission problems, but do not know what to do. For testing purposes I'm using **777** permissions for all files.

I want to start an executable file using PHP.

I tried:

```
<?php
echo system('./FieldTheory');
echo shell_exec('./FieldTheory');
echo exec('./FieldTheory');
?>
```

but none of them actually execute the file.
However I tried executing simple shell script using `system('./script.sh');`:

```
#!/bin/sh
echo "Hello"
/FieldTheory
./FieldTheory
/opt/lampp/htdocs/FieldTheory
./opt/lampp/htdocs/FieldTheory
```

I see the "hello message" but my file is not being executed.

If I execute the file using terminal command: `php testfile.php` my program is being started without difficulties.

> **EDIT**: I tried absolute paths with no effect.

Comment: Have you tried `chmod +x` on `FieldTheory`. Is it a shell script or is it meant to be run with `php` like `php fieldtheroy`? Also, try an absolute path just to be sure.

Answer (score 0):

Double check you php.ini and make sure the exec functions are not disabled:

May have a line like this:

```
disable_functions =exec,passthru,shell_exec,system,proc_open,popen,curl_exec,curl_multi_exec,parse_ini_file,show_source
```